# Pass content to modal via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem when passing data from javascript to bootstrap modal. My code is like following:

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <p id="text_from_js"> </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Bağla</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My table:

```
<td align="center" class="comment more">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cibo neglegentur ea vis. Mea ut ipsum tincidunt moderatius, eu quo dolorum inermis senserit. Meis zril copiosae nam ea, ea per dico cetero. Sea natum tation feugait ea. Sea te facete dicunt, ei soleat iuvaret omnesque mea. Nam ut tantas atomorum honestatis, no nam saepe quaestio. Te animal ocurreret conclusionemque est
                             </td>
```

And javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 50;
$('.more').each(function() {
var content = $(this).html();

if(content.length > showChar) {

  var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
  var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

  var html = c;

  $(this).html(html);
}
});

$('.more')
        .append('<a href="#myModal" style="font-weight: bold;" data-    toggle="modal">&nbsp; &hellip;</a>')
        .click(function() {
            document.getElementById("text_from_js").innerHTML = content;
        });
});
```

And how can I pass content to modal which id is text_from_js?

Comment: You should use AngularJS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand everthing but try to give the table field data-attributes.

```
<td align="center" class="comment more" data-id="1" > ... </td>
```

You can than pass the id with

```
$('.more').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('data-id') );
});
```

Or if you just want to pass the text to the modal.

```
$('.more')
        .append('<a href="#myModal" style="font-weight: bold;" data-toggle="modal">&nbsp; &hellip;</a>')
        .click(function() {
            $("#text_from_js").html( $(this).html() );
        });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 50;
$('.more').each(function() {
var content = $(this).html();

if(content.length > showChar) {

  var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
  var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

  var html = c;
  /* Store the full content to data-content */
  $(this).data('content', $(this).html() );

  $(this).html(html);
}
});

$('.more')
        .append('<a href="#myModal" style="font-weight: bold;" data-    toggle="modal">&nbsp; &hellip;</a>')
        .click(function() {
            /* Get the full content from the data-attribute */
            document.getElementById("text_from_js").innerHTML = $(this).data('content');
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you attention. I want to say that I wanna pass all content which is placed in <td> tag. In your example it only pass shortened text which is 100 character. How can I pass a whole content to modal?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses, Lund. It is working :)